# Orbeon: How to Change workflow-send button icon

Tags: orbeon

How can change icon of the work-flow send button ?
I tried changing caption with

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.detail.labels.workflow-send" value="Fancy Send"/>
```

Is there any such setting by which i can send icon of the button?

Answer (score 1):

Since Orbeon Forms 4.0, the default value [looks like this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-4.3-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml#L125):

```
&lt;i class="icon-arrow-right"/&gt; Send
```

Notice how the icon is part of the value, and uses the [Glyphicons that come with Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons). So [overriding resources](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Overriding-resources) the way you suggested, you can change both the label and the icon.